How can I get the product name and price information
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

def scrape_laptops(driver):
    # Laptop listesini içeren üst elementi bul
    laptop_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="1"]')
    
    # Liste içindeki tüm laptopları bul
    laptops = laptop_list.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')
    print(laptops)
    laptop_data = []
    for laptop in laptops:
        # Her laptop için model ve fiyat bilgisini çek
        model = laptop.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/div/a/div[2]/div[2]/h3')
        for mod in model:
            print(mod)
        print(model)
        price = laptop.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/div/a/div[2]/div[4]')
        laptop_data.append({'model': model, 'price': price})
        print(price)
        print(laptop)
    return laptop_data

# Firefox options
options = Options()
options.headless = True

# Start Firefox webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Go to the Hepsiburada Lenovo computers page
driver.get('https://www.hepsiburada.com/lenovo/bilgisayarlar-c-3000500')

# Accept cookies
button2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
)
button2.click()

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Scroll to the bottom of the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)

# Click the "Show more" button
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/button'))
)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(button).perform()
button.click()
time.sleep(5)

# Scrape laptop models and prices
laptop_data = scrape_laptops(driver)

# Write laptop data to a file
with open("laptop_prices.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for laptop in laptop_data:
        file.write(f"Model: {laptop['model']}, Fiyat: {laptop['price']}\n")

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()


I can get the list of the laptops on the page. When I print the laptops list I get this "<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4e70a140-49c8-4351-b3b8-530ecbb7009f", element="f1ebc5b4-5df1-4873-a28f-7e4188ee7fe2")>" How can I get the product name and price information in this code. It can'T locate the price and product information even if I use CSS_SELECTOR or CLASS_NAME

You have
x = driver.find_element(...)
print(x)

The problem is that x contains a WebElement, not the text contained in that element.
You need to add .text to get the text contained in that element. After updating the sample above, we get
x = driver.find_element(...).text
print(x)


You can't get .text from a list or collection, only a single WebElement. That's the reason for the "'list' object has no attribute 'text'" error. The error is caused by something like
x = driver.find_elements(...).text
                       ^ note the plural, S

but you need to do
x = driver.find_elements(...)
for y in x:
    print(y.text)

where y is a WebElement

When I do that I get the   "'list' object has no attribute 'text'"   error

I've added some more explanation to my answer. You are using .text in the wrong situation... different than what's in my answer.
